# complex type is not available in wcf wsdl

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have created a WCF service, but the service WSDL does not show my classes (complex types).

Below is the service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFedexService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ShipmentReply CreateMultiFedExShipment(RxRdShipment shipment);

    [OperationContract]
    ShipmentReply CreateFedExShipment(RxRdShipment shipment);
}
```

And my class definition is :

```
[DataContract]
public class ShipmentReply
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string MasterTrackingNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<ReplyPackage> Packages { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Response { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public RxNotification Notification { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is I did not find this `ShipmentReply` class in `WSDL`. What is the problem of mine?

Thank you,
Arefin

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, that's normal for WCF. By default, WCF will show just the operations in the WSDL itself - the data structures are documented in XSD files that are linked to the WSDL file.

I'm betting if you look at your WSDL, you'll see something similar to this almost at the top of your WSDL:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigo?xsd=xsd0" 
              namespace="http://tempuri.org/" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigo?xsd=xsd1"  
              namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigo?xsd=xsd2" 
              namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCF_Simple_Service" /> 
</xsd:schema>
```

These are links to the XSD files needed - type in the URL's into your browser, and one of them (most likely the one with the highest number - but doesn't have to be that one) will contain your complex type definition.

Try this URL in your browser (adapt the port and actual URL to what you have):

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloIndigo?xsd=xsd2
```

This should give you the XSD for your complex type

This feature has caused some issues over the past years - some clients cannot deal with this (100% correct and perfectly fine) syntax. So in .NET 4.5, WCF will have a new parameter (`...?singlewsdl`) to output your entire WSDL including all XSD elements - see [What's new in WCF 4.5? A single WSDL file](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2011/09/17/what-s-new-in-wcf-4-5-a-single-wsdl-file.aspx) for some more info on that.

Comment: You are right, Thank you. Can you tell me one thing.. when I use a property of a class that is not datacontract, then I have to use __BackingField, is there any benefit or anything else that you know..

Comment: If you're using `[DataContract] & [DataMember]` attributes - use them everywhere you need to! That's the easiest and safest way - anything else is a hack.